# javascript typeof Object.create !== 'function'

Tags: javascript

It's from Douglas Crockfords's javascript book.

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function')
{
  object.create = function(o) {
          var F = function () {}; 
          F.prototype = o; 
          return new F();
  }
};
```

My question is 
what does this line work?

```
typeof Object.create !== 'function'
```

Thank you.

Comment: `(typeof Object.create !== 'function')` is a guard(ing condition). This code targets every JS environment that has not implemented `Object.create` as of JavaScript 1.8.5. In case of being run in such an environment it provides a poor man's polyfill solution to it (even though providing a typo with `object.create = function ...` instead of `Object.create = function ...` - one might read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill as well.

Answer (score 0):

`new function(){}` returns an object, when by default `Object.create` returns a function.

The reason as to why this line may not work is simply because Douglas Crockford's book was [printed in 2008](http://web-profile.net/wp-content/uploads/douglas-crockford-javascript-the-good-parts.pdf) and back then cross platform compability wasn't guaranteed, as to why that specific condition may have been necessary to ensure that when accessing `Object.create` would work as intended.

```js
console.log(typeof Object.create)
console.log(typeof new function(){})

console.log(Object.create instanceof Object)
console.log(new function(){} instanceof Object)

console.log(Object.create instanceof Function)
console.log(new function(){} instanceof Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a comparison, typeof evaluates if the value is a given type (string, integer, function) so that line is asking if the Object.create (which is a funcion) is not equal to a function.

Situation here is that Object.create it is indeed a function, so that unless you changed Object.craete to something else, the condition will never be true.